# Business Central Admin API - can't delete/stop sessions

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-business-central

Using powershell, I can connect to the business central admin API with a registered app on Azure as per the following setup [Business Central Admin API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/administration-center-api_session_management). I am able to retrieve the list of environments and also the list of sessions etc. One of the key requirements when using the API, is to be able to delete/stop sessions. However when I attempt to do this, it is giving me an error which is basically a null response for the delete method.

```
# This sample authenticates to Azure Active Directory (AAD) an obtains an access token.
# The access token can be used for authenticating to Business Central APIs.
Get-Module
import-Module AzureAD

# Parameters
$aadAppId = "ea954743-####-4025-bc90-############"        # AAD app id
$aadAppRedirectUri = "http://localhost"                   # AAD app redirect URI
$aadTenantId = "46fe5ca5-####-4e42-92e9-############"     # tenant id


# Load Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.2.135\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"

# Get access token
$ctx = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$aadTenantId")
$redirectUri = New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $aadAppRedirectUri
$platformParameters = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters -ArgumentList ([Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Always)
$accessToken = $ctx.AcquireTokenAsync("https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com", $aadAppId, $redirectUri, $platformParameters).GetAwaiter().GetResult().AccessToken
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan 'Authentication complete - we have an access token for Business Central, and it is stored in the $accessToken variable.'

#Get list of environments
$response = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method Get `
    -Uri    "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/admin/v2.11/applications/businesscentral/environments" `
    -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $accessToken")}
Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content))

#List user sessions
$environmentName = "TEST"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method Get `
    -Uri    "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/admin/v2.11/applications/businesscentral/environments/$environmentName/sessions" `
    -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $accessToken")}
Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content))

#Get Session Details
$sessionId = "145197"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method Get `
    -Uri    "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/admin/v2.11/applications/businesscentral/environments/$environmentName/sessions/$sessionId" `
    -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $accessToken")}
Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content))

#Stop/Delete Session
$response = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method Delete `
    -Uri    "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/admin/v2.11/applications/businesscentral/environments/$environmentName/sessions/$sessionId" `
    -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $accessToken")}
Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content))

$response = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method Delete `
    -Uri    "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/admin/v2.11/applications/businesscentral/environments/$environmentName/sessions/$sessionId" `
    -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $accessToken")}
Write-Host "Responded with: $($response.StatusCode) $($response.StatusDescription)"
```

When I try to delete a session, it gives the following error.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> #Stop/Delete Session
$response = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method Delete `
    -Uri    "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/admin/v2.11/applications/businesscentral/environments/$environmentName/sessions/$sessionId" `
    -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $accessToken")}
Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content))
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot convert 'System.Byte[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 
'InputObject'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:6 char:46
+ Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content))
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonComm 
   and
 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $response = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method Delete `
    -Uri    "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/admin/v2.11/applications/businesscentral/environments/$environmentName/sessions/$sessionId" `
    -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $accessToken")}
Write-Host "Responded with: $($response.StatusCode) $($response.StatusDescription)"

Responded with: 204 No Content
```

The scope of the token looks alright, or at least the same as what I have setup in the Azure app, which is delegated permissions. Assuming these are the correct permissions.

"scp":  "Financials.ReadWrite.All user_impersonation",

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, it turns out it is working. A '204 No Content' indicates a successful completion for the Delete method. My confusion stemmed from expecting a response from the delete method when there was none.

[Delete Items - Business Central API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/api/dynamics_item_delete)